# Replace DIV inside another DIV with TEXTAREA, edit text and replace back

Tags: jquery, html, replace, textarea

When you click on ADD, some DIV is added to the Container. **This DIV contain** two divs - **MENU** div and **EDIT** div.

**On focus EDIT** div - I want to **replace this EDIT Div with TEXTAREA** and insert text from EDIT DIV to this TEXTAREA. Than type some text **and on blur** I want **replace TEXTAREA back with DIV** - and insert new edited text from TEXTAREA to this EDIT DIV.

But I have two problems :

1. With targeting. Becouse text from MENU is inserting to TEXTAREA and MENU DIV disappears.
2. When I use doubleclick for the first time to change DIV and TEXTAREA, next time it is happening just on simple click. Why and how to fix it ?

[**jsFIDDLE DEM**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/NpqUB/)

HTML

```
<div id="add" style="background:yellow; width:100px;"> add new </div>
<div id="container"> </div>
```

jQUERY

```
function handler4(){
    var edited_DIV = $(this);
    $(edited_DIV).live({
        click: function() {
            if ($(this).children('textarea').length === 0) {
                var text_from_DIV = $(edited_DIV).find("#edit_div").text();
                $(this).html("<textarea class='inputbox' >"+text_from_DIV+"</textarea>");
                $("textarea.inputbox").focus();
                $("textarea.inputbox").blur(function() {
                    var text_from_TEXTAREA = $(this).val();
                    $(edited_DIV).text(text_from_TEXTAREA);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}


$("#add").on({
   click: function(e) {
        var timestamp = Date.now();
        var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        $('#container').append(function() {
            return $('<div class="add_to_this" id="' + timestamp + '" style="left:' + posx + 'px; top:' + posx + 'px; "><div id="edit_div"><div id="menu" style="color:red;"><b> MENU </b></div>Click here to edit</div></div>').dblclick(handler4).draggable({
                containment: "#container",
                scroll: false,
                cursor: 'lock',
                opacity: 0.55,
                grid: [2, 2]
            }).resizable();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point 2:

> When I use doubleclick for the first time to change DIV and TEXTAREA,
>   next time it is happening just on simple click. Why and how to fix it
>   ?

It is because in your code you are hooking a double click event on div and in the implementation of that event (`handler4`) you are binding single click event which causes the functionality to run on single click

For Point 1:

> With targeting. Becouse text from MENU is inserting to TEXTAREA and
>   MENU DIV disappears.

Well, that is because you are taking text of the div and menu is inside that div

Below is the modified function for you.

```
function handler4() {
    var edited_DIV = $(this);
    if ($(this).children('textarea').length === 0) {
        var text_from_DIV = $(edited_DIV).find("#edit_div").clone().children().remove().end().text();
        var menu = $(this).find("#edit_div").find('#menu');
        $(this).find("#edit_div").text('').append(menu).append("<textarea class='inputbox' >" + text_from_DIV + "</textarea>");
        $("textarea.inputbox").focus();
        $("textarea.inputbox").dblclick(function (event) {
            return false;
        });
        $("textarea.inputbox").blur(function () {
            var text_from_TEXTAREA = $(this).val();
            $(edited_DIV).find("#edit_div").text(text_from_TEXTAREA).prepend(menu);
        });
    }
}
```

I have removed the extra click handler and made some modifications to keep the menu intact.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqadX/)

**EDIT**: added double click event on text area to stop propagation to parent div's double click event

Comment: Year, you are right.. your jsfiddle demo works, but when you try edit text, and than you select all text in textarea by doubleclick, than all text from textarea diseppears.

Comment: Yes, it worrks fine. Thank you very much for help :) 

http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/rqadX/2/

Comment: I'm just watching this code... would not it be better to use in the beginning of this - something like "e.target.id" to detect if edited_DIV was clicked, and if yes replace textarea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kBXTd/)

javascript:

```
$("#edit").live("click",function(){
    $(".inputbox").val($("#menu").text()).show();
    $("#menu").hide();
    $("#save").show();
    $(this).hide();
});

$("#save").live("click",function(){   
    $("#menu").show();
    $("#menu b").html($(".inputbox").val());
    $(".inputbox").hide();
    $("#edit").show();
    $(this).hide();    
});
```